# Why is absolute value of the Laplacian of a function is less than or equal to a constant times magnitude of the Hessian of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Can someone clarify why $|\Delta u| \leq n \; |D^2 u|$ for a function $ u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ that is twice differentiable. Thanks.

Edit: According to Evan's PDE book (appendix A, page 703), $ | D^k u | = 
 \left( \sum_{|\alpha| = k} | D^{\alpha} u|^2 \right)^{1/2}$, the $|D^2 u|$ makes sense to me. I am still searching for how this inequality is derived, maybe something with Jensen's inequality. $ | \sum_i u_{x_i x_i} | \leq C \; |D^2 u|$ for some constant $C$  seems reasonable.

Comment: What is $D^2u$ exactly?

Comment: This cannot be true. By applying a scale factor $\lambda$ to the independent variables, the relation becomes $|\lambda||\Delta u|\le n\lambda^2|D^2u|$ or $|\Delta u|\le n|\lambda||D^2u|$, and you can make $\lambda$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: Seconding @YvesDaoust's observation: the assertion cannot be exactly true, because it does not scale correctly. Maybe the assertion is a (true) variant of what your wrote?

Comment: The main problem is I am not sure what $| D^2 u|$ is despite seeing this notation in several places. If it was the Frobenius norm of the Hessian, then I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: To Yves and Paul; I don’t understand, surely I am missing something. You suggest replacing $u$ with $u_\lambda(x)=u(\lambda x)$. Now, $\Delta u_\lambda(x) = \lambda^2 \Delta u(\lambda x)$. On the other hand, $D^2u_\lambda(x)=\lambda^2 D^2u(\lambda x)$. Where should the contradiction come from? Here I am assuming that $D^2 u(x) =\begin{bmatrix} \partial_{ij} u(x)\end{bmatrix}_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}.$

Comment: You should add what $|D^2 u|$ is. And if this is your main question, then I strongly suggest asking it in the question, otherwise it's simply confusing for everyone.